# Ввод нескольких строк через консоль

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Дана задача на поиск гласных в строках набора знаков типа `char`, на ввод несколько строк знаков. Необходимо определить количество гласных в каждой строке ОТДЕЛЬНО.

Для одной строки все без проблем получается (делал через `BufferedReader`), а как сделать несколько?

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Ввести несколько строк?

Comment: да, по отдельности.

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Введенные строки будем хранить в массиве `String[] strings`.

Сначала вводим размер массива, потом создаем этот массив и вводим сами строки:

```
int n;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Введите количество строк: ");

if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    n = scanner.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.print("Введены некорректные данные!");
    return;
}

String[] strings = new String[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    System.out.print("Введите строку номер " + (i+1) + ": ");
    strings[i] = scanner.next();
}
```

В итоге получим массив строк.

Comment: И как теперь работать с каждой строкой по отдельности?

Comment: @ГеоргийСтепук, Первая строка – это `strings[0]`, вторая – `strings[1]` и так далее.

Comment: Реши следующим способом, но теперь не считает последнюю строку

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String [] s = new String[16];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (i=0; i<16; i++){
s [i]  = reader.readLine();

char [] ch = s[i].toCharArray();
 int count = 0;

 for (j=0; j<ch.length; j++){
     if (ch[j]=='a'||ch[j]=='o'||ch[j]=='e'||ch[j]=='i'||ch[j]=='y'||ch[j]=='u'){
         count++;
     }
     else continue;
     }
 System.out.println(count);
}
```